# SonarQube Scanner failed on Jenkins after custom rules are enabled

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I am running Jenkins job build fine until I enabled one custom rule in SonarQube. The rule is written by me to do a company specific code convention check in Sonar. 
After the rule is enabled, the SonarQube Scanner is complaining **ClassNotFound** Error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.java.checks.JavaFootprint
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    ... 70 more
18:33:57.764 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
18:33:57.765 DEBUG: Execution stop

Please kindly help. Thanks.

The customized code is copied from here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/tree/master/java-custom-rules
And I added some code to check the Tree.Kind.TRIVIA similar to this one:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/CommentedOutCodeLineCheck.java
The idea is to enforce some company comment convention such as checking if the company license statement is at the beginning of each file.

Comment: Some code about what you're actually doing could help.

Comment: I updated the post, please check, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are trying to use `org.sonar.java.checks.JavaFootprint` is not part of the SonarJava api (classes part of the api have api in the package name) and is therefore not found at runtime resulting in the error you see.

This class is not intended for use by custom java rules.

Comment: I see. I copied the rule from the sonar source code https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/CommentedOutCodeLineCheck.java  as a basis  and it is referring JavaFootprint. How can this one referring that class?

Comment: I fixed the issue by removing the class reference.